# How do I highlight an active row in a Infragistics grid?

Tags: c#, highlight, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a row that I activated via code.  However, I need it to be highlighted as well, but can't seem to find the correct property to set.  How can I do this via C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the appearance of the active row through the ActiveRowAppearance

Comment: So, when I select the grid, it highlights a row.  Then, through code, I set another row to active and set the ActiveRowAppearance to highlight the new active row.  But now I have 2 active rows.  How can I make the originally selected row lose it's selection and highlight?

Comment: The UltraGrid can only have one Active row.  Are you using activation or selection?  If you are using selection you should set the SelectedRowAppearance: http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v14.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridOverride~SelectedRowAppearance.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the following solution should work for you:

```
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
ultraGrid1.Rows[0].Activate(); //programatically set active row
ultraGrid1.Selected.Rows.Clear(); //clear your selection of previous row
```

Comment: Without this line : ultraGrid1.Selected.Rows.Clear(); //clear your selection of previous row

The previous active row was disapearing.  I'm glad to have found this solution.